# отличие библиотек <math.h> и <cmath> и вопросы точности

Tags: c++, математика, длинная-арифметика, погрешность, точность

**вопрос 1:**

Подскажите, отличаются ли C++ библиотеки `<math.h>` и `<cmath>` чем-то принципиально (кроме новых функций)?

**вопрос 2:**

Иногда возникают задачи вычисления над близкими значениями, например 
`exp(-(log(x) - a)*(log(x) - a))`, в результате даже `long double` перестаёт помогать и приходится вводить какие-то масштабирующие коэффициенты, чтобы повысить точность, что не очень хорошо.

Может дело в том, что функции exp, log программно-написанные, а не из ALU?
Как вообще люди решают такие проблемы?

Comment: для чисел с плавающей точкой можете использовать готовые библиотеки. `boost::multiprecision::cpp_float` к примеру.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<cmath>` - это по большому счету `<math.h>`, только завернутая в пространство имен `std`. Или `<math.h>` - вытащенные из `std` функции `<cmath>`...

Проблемы с точностью вычислений связаны с ограниченной точностью представлений чисел с плавающей точкой. Библиотечные функции использовали свои "программно-написанные" функции разве что во времена 80386, когда еще было математический сопроцессор - было удовольствие не на каждой машине. Дело не в этом, а в том, что как ни старайтесь, но законы математики не перепрыгнуть, и действительно надо прибегать к математическим преобразованиям для таких вычислений - вплоть до того, что часто изменение последовательности суммирований существенно меняет результат.

Кстати, некоторые компиляторы при `long double` все равно используют обычный `double` - например, Visual C++. Проверьте, что там у вас...

Comment: Visual C++ :) А как заставить его все таки long double использовать? Это же родной тип для ALU

Comment: Думаю, что если в компиляторе это не предусмотрели - никак...

Comment: посмотрел в MSDN - похоже long double воспринимается как обычный double

Answer (score 0):

Для длинной арифметики классика жанра это GMP. Но вообще-то так, чтобы было мало long double это должна быть ОЧЕНЬ специфическая задача. Особенно теперь, когда платформа x86 стала 64-х разрядной.

Comment: подбор коэффициентов в некоторых распределениях - так обратные степени, логарифмы, экспоненты, деления и все это недалеко от нуля и ни везде можно какой-то корректирующий повышающих коэффициент впихнуть, вот точность и едет

Comment: @Zhihar В инженерной практике такого практически не встречается. А если где и встречается, то  простого float за глаза хватает, не говоря уже о double . У Вас должна быть наука, причем на уровне выше мировых стандартов, что само по себе странно. Таких мест, где нужны такие точности (превышающие точность double на платформе 64 бита), в мире раз два и обчелся. Ну, или Вы не в ту сторону копаете.

Comment: не совсем так - мне надо всего лишь подобрать 6 коэффициентов методом наименьших квадратов для логнормального распределения для 1000 точек :) когда реализовал - полез треш, оказалось, что не хватало точности на 3 и 6 линейных коэффициентах, поскольку они линейные, то я ввел масштаб x1000 и всё выправилось, но вот 1,2,5,6 коэффициенты стоят под экспонентой и такие трюки уже не проходят, а там иногда получается exp(-1000) + ... + exp(-10) - что просто жёстко режет точность

P.S. опять же - задача исследовательская, в промышленных масштабах с точностью до 2-3 знаков меня всё устраивает

Comment: Конечно, Вам виднее что там у Вас за модели. Но все равно подозрительно. Скорее всего у Вас где-то ошибка. Потому что double на платформе 64 бита это ОЧЕНЬ большая точность. А может у вас модель неустойчивая, поэтому малые изменения в данных приводят к большим изменениям коэффициентов. Но если у вас модель неустойчивая, тогда Вам не поможет и увеличение разрядности. Все равно будет выходить за разрядную сетку.

Comment: Обычно спасает нормировка. Но бывают и плохие данные, где и нормировка не спасет.